# Web documents that can be edited from iPhone

Tags: webapp-rec

I love Google Docs but can't edit documents from my iPhone.

Can someone recommend a document editor that I can use to edit cloud hosted documents from my iPhone and a PC?

Comment: What kind of documents , XLS, RTF, DOC ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/). Also not fancy, but seems reliable.

Comment: Link only answer. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

http://collabedit.com allows plain text only. The editor isn't great on the iPhone, but works.